# Differences between RHEL developer suite and other versions

Tags: rhel

What does the RHEL developer suite (offered free of charge if I am not mistaken) compared to other RHEL versions that are offered with payed subscriptions?

(besides the support of course)

Comment: To the people voting to close this as opinion-based, I'm curious why — there is a factual list of differences...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find answers to your questions in the [FAQ](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/no-cost-rhel-faq/). In summary, the no-cost Developer Suite includes one physical entitlement for

- RHEL Server (all currently supported versions)
- Software Collections
- Developer Toolset
- Container Development Kit

So with one [Red Hat Developers](https://developers.redhat.com/) account you can register one physical system (with as many VMs as you want). The contents of the downloads are the same as those you'd get with a paid subscription. You also get access to the customer portal and knowledgebase, and portal groups (for discussion). You can only use the no-cost subscription for development and single-user testing, and as you mention there is no support.